# Control not aligned in Stack Panel

Tags: uwp-xaml

XAML for a UWP app (My first real attempt at this)

I have a Stack Panel in a Grid, the orientation is Horizontal.  I want to display, in order, a button, a text block, and two more buttons.

The stack panel occupies its own row of a grid.

In the stack panel the two buttons are not aligning to the right side border. They're sort of hanging out at the 75% position. Using the HorizontalOrientation attribution makes no difference in these two button tags.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnShow" Margin="0,0,5,0">Show</Button>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Nothing searched for yet</TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="btnLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0,5,0">&lt;</Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnRight"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">></Button>


        </StackPanel></Grid></Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of setting `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` on Button, Set it on `StackPanel` itself.

Comment: That just shifted the whole group towards the right side leaving a big gap to the left

Comment: Add another column with `Width *` to Grid and Move your TextBox to That column. Last Column should only contain the Buttons that you want to move to right.

Answer (score 0):

This should work according to your Requirement.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnShow" Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                Content="Show" Grid.Row="3" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Nothing searched for yet" 
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button x:Name="btnLeft" Margin="5,0" Content="&lt;" />
            <Button x:Name="btnRight" Content=">" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Basically I added a third Column, Moved first two items into the first two columns with their own Width Index and Third Column specifically for Buttons.